# Order by repeated secret_id

Tags: mysql, sql

How i can order this table by the repeated secret_id :

This table is the likes table of my website, there are some post in wich people can like it by a button and on my database are seved the ip from which the post is liked and also his secret_id.

A repeat of the id corresponds to a post liked some times.

So i want to order by the most repeated `secret_id`. How i can do that ?

I want to order with a php code on my html page

For example like : SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY .....

```
INSERT INTO `likes` (`id`, `ip`, `secret_id`) VALUES
(1, '95.234.109.87', 3),
(2, '95.234.109.87', 7),
(3, '95.234.109.87', 6),
(4, '95.234.109.87', 1),
(5, '91.252.43.7', 7),
(6, '91.252.43.7', 4),
(7, '91.252.43.7', 3),
```

Comment: ` GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ` try grouping and then, ordering by the same column...

Comment: *"most repeated id"* - Your id's look to be unique; I think you want most repeated `secret_id`, correct and/or `ip`?

Comment: @Fred -ii-  i mean most repeated secret_id  sorry

Comment: I edited your question. You might want to also change *"A repeat of the `id` corresponds"* also.

Answer (score 2):

You can find count's for each `secret_id`, join it with main table and order by it's count like so:

```
select t1.*
from likes t1
inner join (
    select `secret_id`, count(*) cnt
    from likes
    group by `secret_id`
) t2 on t1.`secret_id` = t2.`secret_id`
order by t2.cnt desc, t1.`id`;
```

Comment: the name of my table is : likes

Comment: what i have to put instead t1 and t2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT count(secret_id) AS SID, secret_id FROM likes GROUP BY secret_id ORDER BY SID DESC;
```

Its supposed to group all the secret_id if they're repeated, then, count the ammount and ordering them knowing how much secret_ids are repeated.

Hope is what you want.